# Is there any ethernet and 4G gateway for PLC?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, ethernet, plc, automation

I'm new in PLC programming and used only Siemens Logo. The problem I'm facing is that I can not find any gateway device that can directly send the data to server. I want to avoid using PC for simply sending or receiving data. I checked Ignition software. It's great, but it needs a PC. I found many gateways in Alibaba, but those are not programmable like PLCs.

Comment: hasn't the logo already an ethernet device? IIRC it's *designed* to use some kind of cloud service. Just attach it *behind* a router and it should be already able to communicate

Comment: https://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/WW/Catalog/Product/6GK7142-7BX00-0AX0

Comment: I think you are talking about this. I just found it.

Answer (score 1):

Safety for a PLC is very important, you don't want malware in your PLC or that third parties have access.
Use a VPN gateway, such as Tosibox, EWON or develop one yourself with Mikrotik.
They provide you with safe remote access to the PLC, and optionally, the PLC can access some internet. They also fix any [CGNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) issue.

In any case, you PLC must never be found by shodan.io or similar network mapping indexers.